# angular-cli tab data-toggle not working with an error

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm using the angular framework in client-side.

I added a new module and some component in the project than I added two tabs on my page as follows:

```
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs in" id="tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#number1">
          <i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>
          <span>tab 1</span>
        </a>
      </li>

      <li>
        <a data-toggle="tab" href="#number2">
          <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
          <span>tab 2</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>


    <div class="no-padding">
    <div class="body">
      <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">

        <first-component class="tab-pane fade active in padding-10 no-padding-bottom" id="number1"></first-component>
        <second-component class="tab-pane fade" id="number2"></second-component>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click in the tabs I catch the following error:

```
    ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'number1'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'number1'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:2469)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:2450)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:831)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:788)
    at zone.js:892
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:17280)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
    at push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:502)
    at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:487)
window.console.error @ VM669:37
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:15714
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:15762
next @ core.js:17761
schedulerFn @ core.js:13504
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13488
(anonymous) @ core.js:17311
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:391
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:150
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:17248
onHandleError @ core.js:17311
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:395
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:164
_loop_1 @ zone.js:694
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:703
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:608
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:502
ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:487
timer @ zone.js:2281
setTimeout (async)
scheduleTask @ zone.js:2302
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:410
onScheduleTask @ zone.js:301
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.scheduleTask @ zone.js:404
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleTask @ zone.js:238
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.scheduleMacroTask @ zone.js:261
scheduleMacroTaskWithCurrentZone @ zone.js:1245
(anonymous) @ zone.js:2317
proto.(anonymous function) @ zone.js:1569
(anonymous) @ router.js:4064
schedulerFn @ core.js:13504
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:13488
(anonymous) @ common.js:151
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:423
onInvokeTask @ core.js:17280
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask @ zone.js:422
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask @ zone.js:195
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:498
invokeTask @ zone.js:1744
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1770
zone.js:199 Uncaught TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at console.window.console.error (<anonymous>:39:101)
    at defaultErrorLogger (core.js:15714)
    at ErrorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError (core.js:15762)
    at Object.next (core.js:17761)
    at SafeSubscriber.schedulerFn [as _next] (core.js:13504)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:196)
    at SafeSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:134)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:77)
    at Subscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:54)
```

I know need some change to my routing file but I don't know how.

Thanks for taking the time and share your ideas

Answer (score 0):

With Angular, you typically would setup up a RouterOutlet for the content that will change when the route changes.

Then you can use a [routerLink] to specify the route that you want to change.

```
<a [routerLink]="['/basecomp/tabname1']>Tab1 Link</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/basecomp/tabname1']>Tab2 Link</a>
```

Then in your router module, you can create a child route to load the correct component.

```
appRoutes: Routes = [
  { 
    path: "baseComp", component, CompoenntThatHasTabPage,
    children: [
       { path: '', component: Tab1Component },
       { path: 'tabname1', component: Tab1Component },
       { path: 'tabname1', component: Tab2Component }
    ]
   }     
 ];
```

Comment: @SaeidMirzaei I can see your new to StackOverflow.    The quality of the questions you ask goes a long way into getting the response you need.   The original question lacks routing code but that is clearly what you think is wrong.    So I guessed to answer. "It's not working"  keeps me guessing.   Take some time to rearticulate your question